# Visual Studio 2017 editor new line has only one tab

Tags: visual-studio

I have VS 2017. When I add new line (I hit enter), new line has only one tab. It should has two tabs. And previous I had always two tabs but from several days I have only one tab

Comment: You probably have some different Indentation settings than you expect. Tools > Options > Text Editor > (your language, e.g. C#) > Formatting > Indentation. Look at the options and see if you are missing something such as Indent block contents.

Comment: Ok, but why part of .cs files have two tabs and part of them has only one? If I would have something wrong in settings all .cs files should have only one tab